# Can I set different message tones for SMS based on the sender or content

Tags: sms, ringtone

At my workplace we have a paging system and when I'm on call I can get paged anytime.
The messages that the paging system sends start the same way, is there a way that I could set a different ringtone for those messages?

I guess my question is quite similar to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15580/alerts-reminders-based-on-sms-content

I have a Lumia 720 with the Amber Update installed.

If this is not possible does someone know if WP apis allow for access to SMSes, I wouldn't mind trying to roll out a solution on my own.

Comment: Based on the sender or content? totally different meanings.

Comment: @HaLaBi you are right of course. In my case it doesn't matter as a filter on either the sender or the content would serve the purpose. I'll edit the title of the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of what you are asking for is possible at this time - even with the GDR2/Amber update.

It's not possible to...

1. Set a custom SMS/Message tone per contact or filter
2. Access the phone's SMS/Message store via API, or implement anything similiar yourself.

These features [may appear](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2281201-custom-sounds-for-sms-mms-email-notifications-e) [in the future](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api) so keep an eye out for GDR3 (due late 2013) and the WP 8.1 update due early 2014.

**UPDATE**

It appears this feature has been [added to the GDR3 Preview which is available to developers](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/10/14/announcing-our-third-windows-phone-8-update-plus-a-new-developer-preview-program.aspx). GDR3 is expected to be available for all WP8 devices in November.

Comment: Any sources?
That's a bummer. But I guess I'll have to live with that for now.

Comment: I've added links to the feature requests, which confirm the features don't currently exist - I also know this from looking into the matter in the early WP7 days and keeping an eye on it since.

Comment: Just a quick update, the GDR3 Preview was released and now it's possible to have a different SMS tone for each person. If you're a WP developer, you can get the GDR3 Preview now - otherwise, you'll have to wait until November (estimated release)

Comment: Awesome!
I do have a developer account, will give it a spin.

Comment: Confirmed, you can do this with GDR3